# Take return value from python script from php

Tags: php, python, return

I run a python script from a php script and i want to php take return value from python(return value is a list). I use exec() function for running python. 
How can i do that? Thx

Comment: What do you mean python script returns a list? Do you mean you are printing the list?

Comment: The list is filled with some kind of objects. I need to take values of that objects and use it in php.

Answer (score 2):

You can print your result in JSON format and the exec() function will return the string. This string can be used to retrieve your value using any JSON decoder.